# How to dynamically update badge count on Badge in NavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have the following navigation bar in my flutter app:

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(
  items: [
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: appState.itemCard.cardItems.isNotEmpty   // only show Badge when items are cardItems
          ? badges.Badge(                            // This is the Badge
              badgeContent: Text(appState
                  .itemCard.cardItems.values
                  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
                  .toString()),
              child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            )
          : const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
      label: 'Card',
    ),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      label: 'Menu',
    ),
  ],
  currentIndex: selectedIndex,
  onTap: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = value;
    });
  },
)
```

The issue is that when I make changes to the `itemCard.cardItems` the badge count doesn't update until I click on another `NavigationBarItem` like `Home`.
How can I achieve that the badge updates immediately when I add items to the `itemCard.cardItems`?

## Edit - Solution, thank you @[Abhishek Karad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14740184/abhishek-karad)

I've created a `ValueNotifier` for the value in the `ItemCard` Class:

```dart
class ItemCard {
  Map<Item, int> cardItems = {};
  double totalPrice = 0.0;
  ValueNotifier<int> totalItems = ValueNotifier<int>(0); // <-- this one
}
```

In the next step I wrapped the icon of the corresponding `BottomNavigationBarItem` with the `ValueListenableBuilder`:

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: ValueListenableBuilder( // wrapped Icon
      builder: (context, value, child) => badges.Badge(
            showBadge:
                appState.itemCard.totalItems.value > 0,
            badgeContent: Text(appState
                .itemCard.totalItems.value
                .toString()),
            child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          ),
      valueListenable: appState.itemCard.totalItems), // ValueNotifier
  label: 'Card',
),
```

Comment: update `itemCard.cardItems` inside setState

Comment: can you show the code where you update `itemCard.cardItems`?

Comment: What is `appState`? Is it a member, a provider etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
List<CartModel> appState.itemCard.cardItems =[]
```

in your AppState file

Replace it to

```
ValueNotifier<List<CartModel>> appState.itemCard.cardItems =ValueNotifier<List<CartModel>>([]);
```

And replace

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: appState.itemCard.cardItems.isNotEmpty   // only show Badge when items are cardItems
          ? badges.Badge(                            // This is the Badge
              badgeContent: Text(appState
                  .itemCard.cardItems.values
                  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
                  .toString()),
              child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            )
          : const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
      label: 'Card',
    ),
```

to

```
ValueListenableBuilder(builder : (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
            // This builder will only get called when the _counter
            // is updated.
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('$value'),
                child!,
              ],
            );},valueListenable: appState
                  .itemCard.cardItems)
```

if you are already using ValueNotifier then just wrap your widget with ValueListenableBuilder

For More https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html